# GNOME 3, reset GNOME 2 look and feel

Tags: gnome, gnome3, gtk

I just installed and started *GNOME 3*, and after starting it I notice that all applications using *GTK2* are still maintaining the old look-and-feel. I would like to make this consistent.

I'm thinking of removing the *GTK2* setting files (is this effective?), but I get lost: there are many places where those settings could be stored!

Any hint?

Comment: By "old", do you mean Clearlooks, or the default darkgray Raleigh theme?

Comment: @grawity By "old" I mean that is not consistent with the GTK3 stuff. For instance, if I set a different font on GNOME3 I don't experience any modification.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After removing many configuration directories (included the ones suggested by [lornix](https://superuser.com/a/448943/46484)), I've noticed that the style was reset, but of course it was not consistent with the GTK3 theme. After searching on the Internet, I've learned that the setting can be modified through the `~/.gtkrc-2.0` file:

```
style "font" {
    font_name = "Ubuntu 8"
}
widget_class "*" style "font";
gtk-font-name = "Ubuntu 8";
```

By setting this values as in my GTK3 configuration, I fixed the problem. This solution is not perfect: of course if I want to change the settings again, I would need to change the values twice, once for each configuration.

Answer (score 1):

Have you removed the Gnome2 configuration files for those applications?  They may have retained their settings from your previous installation of Gnome2.

.gconf
.gconfd
.gnome2
.gnome2_private

all show up on my system.  I imagine there are others.